# Returning success on query successfully in PHP to java

Tags: java, php, mysql, json

I need to check if the username is already present in the database.If so then only Login. After login,I need a response to be sent from php file to java class saying success.
 When I access the result array in my java file using Json,it is giving NULL though the Username is already present in Database.

Any Help?

I am using the below Php and java code

```
<?php

include("db_config.php");

$myusername = $_GET['username'];
$mypassword = $_GET['password'];



$sql="SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE username='$myusername' and  password='$mypassword'";    

echo $sql;

$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$active=$row['active'];

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1)
{
$result['login'] == 'success';

}
else 
{
$result['login'] == 'failed';
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

This is my Java code

```
btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
            username= textFieldUserName.getText().toString();
            password = textFieldPassword.getText().toString();
            //  discount = textFieldDiscount.getText().toString();

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();





            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password ));



            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);


            try {           

                status = json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);
                System.out.println(" status is "+status);

                if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Login success");
                }   


            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }           

        }

    });
```

Also,I tried 
                                                                                                         if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
which returns 200 if OK from the from the server.

[Edit: Code ReFormation]

Comment: Try to pass querystring.. like call the file using `http://example.com/new.java?success=true` and `GET` in the java file to access the querystring... Correct me if I am wrong somewhere in interpreting your question..

Answer (score 0):

use this code for `java`

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject)jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);
try {           
   //status = json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);
   String status = (String) json.get("login");
   System.out.println(" status is "+status);

   if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
   {
       System.out.println("Login success");
   }   
 }
```

Comment: @DevAndro What does `json` returns?

Comment: @DevAndro I used this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/ check it.

Comment: (String)json.get("login")                   It is returning NULL